# How do I tell an INSTEAD OF UPDATE trigger to continue and ignore my statement?

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers

I have an `INSTEAD OF UPDATE` trigger that checks to see if I am populating a column called deleted_date, if so it will then perform an operation.

Everything was working great until I realized that if I try to update any other data my trigger runs and my update is ignored.

Other solutions I have found on stack explain that doing an `IF/ELSE` and then doing an `UPDATE` on the original table after joining the "inserted" table to it. This will work, however, this also means if I modify a tables columns in any way I have to go back and edit my trigger.

Is there a way to say `ELSE CONTINUE DEFAULT ACTION` to basically say "leave this trigger and update the records you would have normally done in the first place"

Comment: Are you using mysql or sql server?

Comment: Edited to show "MS-SQL 2008".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you *always* want the update to happen, and *sometimes* want some additional processing to happen, you could use change to using an `AFTER` trigger (unless you're working with a view).
Otherwise, you need to do the update statement inside the trigger.

Answer (score 1):

No. When an instead of update trigger is fired, you cannot return to the default action.  Any updates to the data in the table must be done by your trigger logic